# Existence of $I=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2} (x^2+1)\,d\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I've a doubt:

> Does the following integral exist? $$I=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2} (x^2+1)\,d\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor$$

As far I know $dx$ is considered as the smallest element and it undergoes very minor increment. I don't think so $d\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor$ can be considered as smallest element as it'll be 0. Also the increment it undergoes is huge, i.e., it directly jumps from 0 to 1. I think that this violates the definition of integration.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. If that integral exists, then why does it violate the basic law of integration? Also how do we evaluate it(if it exists)?

Thanks.

Comment: See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral  .

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I didn't understand. Can you explain me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral in the question is not meant to be a Riemann integral. It is, however, a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. These are defined as follows: Given $f$ and $g$ on an interval $[a,b]$ one considers tagged partitions $${\cal P}:\quad a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b$$ and sums
$$S(f,g,{\cal P}):=\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)\bigl(g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1}\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$

The integral $$\int_a^b f(x)\>dg(x)$$ is then the limit of such sums under refinement of ${\cal P}$, if it exists.

In the example at hand $g(x):=\lfloor x\rfloor$. This function gives  a contribution to the sums $(1)$ only for the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ with $x_{i-1}<1\leq x_i$ and for the last interval, where $g$ jumps from $1$ to $2$. It is then intuitively clear that the value of the integral is simply
$$f(1)+f(2)=7\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

By parts,

$$\int_{0}^{2} (x^2+1)\,d\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor=\left.(x^2+1)\lfloor x\rfloor\right|_0^2-\int_0^2\lfloor x\rfloor d(x^2+1)=10-\int_1^2\,d(x^2+1).$$

Comment: Won't it be $d\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor$ in the second integral?

Comment: @AdityaKumar: no, why ?

Comment: That's because in the main integral you are evaluating it wrt $d\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor$

Comment: @AdityaKumar: but then I performed integration by parts. I am rewriting it for your convenience.